# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../App.vue'

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I follow this tutorial [https://www.tutsmake.com/larave-vue-js-spa-crud-example-tutorial/] after finish copy paste and understanding the code and I'm getting the error [https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUnP6.png].

App.vue
https://pastebin.com/aDcppkRF

app.js
https://pastebin.com/PiYZPM0d

routes.js

```
[https://pastebin.com/km1EXCxL][3]
```

Comment: `../App.vue` is wrong fix this as `./App.vue`

Comment: my code like this ./App.vue instead of this ../App.vue

Comment: check in this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUnP6.png